# Sum NSArray of NSDecimalNumbers

Tags: objective-c

I know you can sum an array of NSNumbers by using the @sum.self keypath, but does that also work with NSDecimalNumbers? Will the result be accurate?

EDIT: To be more specific, here is code I know that works with NSNumber.

```
NSNumber *sum = [numArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`NSDecimalNumber` is a subclass of `NSNumber`, so it will inherit this ability.

Also, I would recommend using one of these:

```
NSDecimalNumber *sum = [numArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.floatValue"];

float sum = [[numArray valueforKeyPath:@"@sum.floatValue"] floatValue];
```

Comment: Doesn't using `floatValue` negate the precision of `NSDecimalNumber`?

Comment: Yes, it does. This is a very bad practice.